# iOS UILocalNotification showing a date/time in the past

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to present a UILocalNotification with a date/time in the past but, in spite of the fireDate specified, the notification always refers to the time of the delivery.
As for the UILocalNotification class reference, In case of fireDate nil or in the past, the notification is delivered immediately. Do you know if there is a way to show a time in the past (instead of "now")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work on iOS :( (at least on iOS7.0 this is KO):
Event if the date of the `UILocalNotification` is set to the past, the notification center shows 'now' instead of 'X min ago' for instance.
This is a pity because **this can be useful when an event happened when you had no network connection**: you were not informed of it, but once you detect it, you may want to apply the real *past* date value of this event so that when the user is notified of the event on the screen, he knows that it didn't really happened 'now' but maybe '10 minutes ago'.

The MacOS X equivalent of `UILocalNotification` is `NSUserNotification` and handles properly such situation ! 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html
A difference is made between the `deliveryDate` (the date of the event, that may be in the past), and the `actualDeliveryDate` (the date when the event has been delivered / shown to the user). And the date shown on the screen is the `deliveryDate`